# Emulating link element

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a dynamic page that contains many links to different parts of the page, but none of them are actual `<a>` elements - most of them are table rows, in fact. I make them look like links via CSS and use Javascript to load up the content via AJAX. It works fine, however I would like to make them more link-like, by having them show the URL in bottom left when you hover over the element, and enable native Ctrl+click/context menu functionality. Is it possible without using actual `<a>` elements?

Or should I use `<a>` instead of `<tr>`'s and make them look like rows using `display: table-row`? But then I would run into issues like CSS having no support for `colspan` attribute.

Comment: You'll need to show your relevant ("*[mcve]*") code for us to help, but I strongly suspect that - for this to work as you require - you'll need to use `<a>` elements, instead of emulating them.

Comment: I'm not sure how code would help here as it seems to be a pretty general question. Is it possible to emulate `<a>` behavior without using the element itself? Although I suppose it would indeed be easier to use `<a>` and make it behave like for instance `<tr>` instead.

Comment: Just use an `<a>` inside your table cell. Semantically too you wouldn't want any other element to behave and look like an anchor. You would definitely wanna use a real anchor in there.

Comment: I strongly echo @Praveen Puglia 's responses here. If you still want to pursue your approach, since you've probably added a click event to the <tr> tag via js, you would need to add the other events as well. (i.e., onmouseover, etc, ...). For the status bar showing the url, that would probably be more browser specific.

Comment: I didn't mean actually emulating the status bar and context menu, but was rather looking for some attribute that would allow a row appear similar to a link, but I guess that's not possible? Otherwise I would have to add too many `a`'s and have to make sure they actuall span entire cells. I've just reworked the page to use CSS tables instead of actual HTML tables which allows me to use `a`'s instead of `tr`'s but I had to get rid of some HTML-only things like `colspan`.